# Custom class in Swift conversion

Tags: swift

I have created a custom class called PhoneTranslator (based on Xamarin's "Hello, iOS" guide). It looks like this:

```
class PhoneTranslator {
    func ToNumber(raw:String) -> String {
      var newNumber = raw.isEmpty ? "" : raw.uppercaseString
      //newNumber operations...
      return newNumber
    }
}
```

Then I have a ViewController standard class. I want to do this:

```
var translatedNumber : String?

    if let inputText = PhoneNumberTextField.text //getting text from UITextField
    {
        translatedNumber = PhoneTranslator.ToNumber(inputText) //error
    }
```

Then in line with ToNumber method I get an error *Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'PhoneTranslator'*.

What am I doing wrong? All input and output types seems to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
class PhoneTranslator {
    class func ToNumber(raw:String) -> String {
        var newNumber = raw.isEmpty ? "" : raw.uppercaseString
        return newNumber
    }
}
```

Your function was not a class function. Therefore you need an instance first. Above code defines the `ToNumber` function as `class func`.

Alternatively create an instance of the `PhoneTranslator` first:

```
translatedNumber = PhoneTranslator().ToNumber(inputText)
```

Note the `()` after `PhoneTranslator`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively no need to make a class function. You can have a shared Instance which will be a singleton object for the entire application. With this singleton object you can call the **PhoneTranslator** methods

```
class PhoneTranslator {

    static let sharedInstance = PhoneTranslator()

    func ToNumber(raw:String) -> String {
          var newNumber = raw.isEmpty ? "" : raw.uppercaseString
          //newNumber operations...
          return newNumber
          }
    }
```

And you can call it this way

```
translatedNumber  = PhoneTranslator.sharedInstance.ToNumber(inputText)
```

Comment: well, that is neither more developer-friendly nor more performant, it is probably worse in every way. It is longer to write, it introduces a kind of a singleton (bad), it constantly holds one object of the type in memory. Why?

Comment: This approach supports lazy initialization because Swift lazily initializes class constants (and variables), and is thread safe by the definition of let